# ArcGis map on Android not displaying after implementing Node server

Tags: java, android, node.js, arcgis-js-api

I'm developing an Android ArcGIS map application where I've successfully added an API key, initialized the map on a MapView, and included the necessary dependencies for Esri by adding the Maven URL. Despite having an active internet connection and granting internet permission in the manifest file, the map is not displaying properly in the app. Instead, I only see the "Powered by Esri" attribution at the bottom, indicating it's licensed for developers. Interestingly, before integrating my app with a MySQL database using a Node.js server, the map displayed correctly. Now, however, it's not working. What could be causing this issue?

Even after attempting to change the API key and experimenting with different basemaps, the problem persists. The map still fails to display correctly in the application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                                                                                                     
<network-security-config>                                                        
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">                          
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.0.102</domain>                    
    </domain-config>                                                              
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.